# Cancellation law for invertible matricies

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Show that the cancellation law holds for invertible matrices. i.e.
if $A \in GL_n(R), B, C \in M_{n×m}(\mathbb{R})$ and $AB = AC$, then $B = C$.

What I tried:

I know that I can prove this by actually looking at each element of the matrix and multiplying them out, but is there a more elegant/cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We assume that $$AB=AC$$
Multiply on the left by the matrix $A^{-1}$, whose existence is guaranteed by hypothesis.  We conclude that $$A^{-1}AB=A^{-1}AC$$
and hence $$B=C$$

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is in the general linear group, then $A^{-1}$ exists. Then
$$
B=I_n B = (A^{-1}A)B=A^{-1}(AB)=A^{-1}(AC)=(A^{-1}A)C=I_n C = C.
$$